# Check if a option is selected, by id

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check if a option is selected and the same thing will be done for other options so i think i need to check it by id or if a item from a optgroup is selected.

```html
<optgroup label="AMD CPU">
<option id="ryzen" value="r3-1300x">Ryzen 3 1300x</option>
<option id="ryzen" value="r3-1300">Ryzen 3 1200</option>
<option id="ryzen" value="r5-1600x">Ryzen 5 1600x</option>
<option id="ryzen" value="r5-1400">Ryzen 5 1400</option>
<option id="ryzen" value="r7-1800x">Ryzen 7 1800x</option>
<option id="ryzen" value="r7-1700">Ryzen 7 1700</option>
</optgroup>
```

I would need something like:

```js
if(docuemnt.getElementById("ryzen") == true{
   alert("amd cpu")
```

Comment: `id`s **must** be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values for `id` attributes should be unique. If you want something to reference that is shared across multiple elements, use a class.

```
<select id="amd" label="AMD CPU">
    <option class="ryzen" value="r3-1300x">Ryzen 3 1300x</option>
    <option class="ryzen" value="r3-1300">Ryzen 3 1200</option>
    <option class="ryzen" value="r5-1600x">Ryzen 5 1600x</option>
    <option class="ryzen" value="r5-1400">Ryzen 5 1400</option>
    <option class="ryzen" value="r7-1800x">Ryzen 7 1800x</option>
    <option class="ryzen" value="r7-1700">Ryzen 7 1700</option>
</select>
```

Now, to figure out what option is selected, do:

```
var select_id = document.getElementById("amd");
var option = select_id.options[select_id.selectedIndex].value;
```

Notice that you reference the `select` id, and from that you tell it to get the option that is currently selected within that `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to check the value of the `<select>` tag containing your `<optgroup>`? I have no problems retrieving the selected value like this: `<input type="button" value="test" onClick="alert(document.getElementById('ryzen').value)">`

Where `ryzen` was actually applied to the `<select>` tag, instead of the elements within it.

And you can test the value to make sure the user selected something other than a default option.